# How to filter pandas dataframe with more than 2 conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. I want to filter the dataframe based on two columns. For one column there is one condition and for the other column there are 3 conditions.

This code for the one condition in each column works fine:

```
filtered_df = df[(df['col1'] == 'cond1') & (df['col2'] == 'cond2)]
```

When I expand this to 3 conditions for the second column I get an empty dataframe as a result.

```
filtered_df = df[(df['col1'] == 'cond1') & (df['col2'] == 'cond2) & (df['col2'] == 'cond3) & (df['col2'] == 'cond4)]
```

How can I filter with more than 2 conditions?

Comment: Pandas allow you to use multiple filtering i suggest you to check your conditions.

Comment: second code syntax is incorrect (quotation) and `col2` can not be `cond2` and `cond4` at same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filtered_df = df[(df['col1'] == 'cond1') & (df['col2'] == 'cond2) & (df['col2'] == 'cond3) & (df['col2'] == 'cond4)]
```

please be careful... in your code there are four condition that contradictory:

`col2` can not be `cond2` and `cond3` and `cond4` at same time

so you must use `or`:

```
filtered_df = df[(df['col1'] == 'cond1') & ((df['col2'] == 'cond2') | (df['col2'] == 'cond3') | (df['col2'] == 'cond4'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's correct but there is missing ' in your code, try this:

```
filtered_df = df.loc[(df['col1'] == 'cond1') & (df['col2'] == 'cond2') & (df['col2'] == 'cond3') & (df['col2'] == 'cond4')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
(df['col2'] == 'cond2') & (df['col2'] == 'cond3')
```

There couldn't be a value that both equal to `cond2` and equal to `cond3` at the same time. You may want `|`

Better is to use `isin` for a list of value

```
df['col2'].isin(['cond2', 'cond3'])
```